# Downgrade from 14.10 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, downgrade

Is there any easier/different way to downgrade from 14.10 to 14.04 other than USB? I know it's a developmental branch which may make things different, but they want 14.04 now (LTS). A lot of data is riding on this machine which is part of a server cluster.

Any one have any luck using this?:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto

Comment: 14.10 isn't out yet

Comment: The poster is likely using a daily build of 14.10, which is available [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/).

Comment: For these types of questions (we have had many like this over time) - we have duplicated these to our canonical "how to revert" question.